# Jquery text value reading wrong integer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi All I am with an interesting issue, I am trying to get input text value from table column. When I start to read loop I am getting wrong integer value with my text value, if my text value is 150, I m getting 150.33  but if I put an alert in between the loop then I m getting correct value, what could be the reason for this? any idea?

```
//loop  for table column read...
$('#IGrid tr').each(function () {
   var prev_discount = isNumber($('td input[name="Discount"]', this).val());
    alert(prev_discount);
});
```

Comment: Can you please share isNumber function?

Comment: I second that the problem lies probably with with isNumber ... You should also check if the object 'this' is actually pointing to what you want, jQuery's each may have re-binded it.

Comment: @MatthiasWilhelm when looping selector collection, `this` within `$.each` is the current element...in this case a `<tr>`. That behavior is always consistent

Comment: @charlietfl: ok thanks, I didn't know that. I had often problems with 'this' inside of jQuery functions, so this looked dangerous to me.